# Using @CrossOrigin in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cors

I'm using latest Spring Boot (1.2.7.RELEASE). I would like to use the [`@CrossOrigin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html) annotation from the package `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation` as described in [**CORS Support**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cors) section in Spring docs.

I'd think I already have all the necessary dependencies (via Spring Boot defaults), but this is confusing: `CrossOrigin` is not found, even though stuff like `RestController` from the same package works!

[image]

```
Error:(8, 47) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CrossOrigin
  location: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
```

What's going on? Has `CrossOrigin` been removed from later versions of Spring-MVC, or am I missing some dependency?

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, looks like the latest Spring Boot release, `1.2.7.RELEASE` at the moment, is too old to have a version of Spring MVC with `CrossOrigin`. ([Spring Boot 1.2.7 uses Spring version 4.1.8](https://spring.io/blog/2015/10/16/spring-boot-1-2-7-available-now)).

I updated to latest Spring Boot 1.3 release candidate (`1.3.0.RC1`) and it works:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RC1</version>
</parent>
```

Also needed to specify `spring-milestones` repository in `pom.xml` to be able to use the non-release version.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

#### Update: override Spring version

As Stéphane Nicoll pointed out, a simpler way to get Spring 4.2.2 classes (such as `CrossOrigin`) into use is this:

```
<properties> 
    <!-- ... -->
    <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: You can use Spring Boot `1.2.7` with Spring Framework `4.2.2.RELEASE` if you want as well. Forward override is not a problem. Please make sure to remove the override when you migrate to 1.3

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll: Thanks! Which dependency exactly (groupId/artifactId) should I use for that? (Just `spring-web`? Or also `spring-core`, `spring-context` etc? What's the easiest way? See pom.xml in the question.)

Comment: By the way, is there an easy way to see which versions of all the default dependencies come with a specific Spring Boot version? I was struggling to find that info earlier today.

Comment: <properties><spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version></properties>

Comment: Probably not a good idea to ask additional questions in a comment... http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions

Answer (score 0):

@CrossOrigin annotation is used to provide support for cross domains,

ie nothing but from different domains also we can  access that service

by default it is true.

we can access the services from cross domains also.